# In bash, find list of files for which a related file does not exist

Tags: bash, find

I have a list of videos for which I'd like to convert. To build up the file list I need to work with, I use the following:

```
file_list=( $(find . \( \
    -name '*.[Mm][Oo][Vv]' -o \
    -name '*.[Aa][Vv][Ii]' -o \
    -name '*[!-][!h][!v][!c][!1].mp4' \
    \) -print) )

task_list=()
for i in "${!file_list[@]}" ; do
    m="${file_list[$i]}"
    n="${m%.*}-hvc1.mp4"
    if [[ ! -f "$n" ]] ; then
        task_list+=("$m")
    fi
done
```

Is there some way I might be able to fold this logic into `find` and get the file list in one pass, or am I stuck with this two pass script where I do a `find` and then I have to do a loop?

Answer (score 0):

May be this works for you

```
    task_list=()
    for file in  *.[Mm][Oo][Vv] *.[Aa][Vv][Ii] *[!-][!h][!v][!c][!1].mp4 ; do
        n="${file%.*}-hvc1.mp4"
        if [[ ! -f "$n" ]] ; then
            task_list+=("$file")
        fi
    done
```

Does not use `find` but I suppose that it is not a must.